# how to use the returned value of a query as a paramater for the where clause of my subquery? in sql server

Tags: sql-server, subquery, where-clause

[image: I want to use the repairid returned as a parameter for my subquery]

i want to use the RepairId that is returned by my main query, as a parameter for my subquery, but when i try, btw the repairid is just also the AccessoryAdjustDetailsId so maybe sql server got confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `co-related sub query`.
Basically, assign an alias to your outer table in JOIN condition i.e.

```
JOIN DAMAGEACCESSORYDETAILS A ON..
```

and then, in your sub query, you can use:

```
SELECT Quantity FROM DamageAccessoryDetails
WHERE
AccessoryAdjustedDetailsId = A.RepairID
```

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't solve the problem, btw this is closed i use the With clause. thank you for the effort :)